# Why is this the output for the following code?

Tags: python

I am having trouble understanding why the output for this code is 16. I apologize if I am formatting anything incorrectly, I am new to coding.

I have written the code a couple times to make sure I was formatting it correctly

```
x = 1
while x < 10:
    x += x
print(x)
```

The output that is printing for me is 16.

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Comment: `x += x` is essentially the same as `x *= 2`. You double `x` until it gets bigger than 10. Starting from 1, the first `x` that's not `x<10` is... 16.

Comment: I recommend indenting the `print` to be inside the while loop. Then you can see x on each loop iteration. It should make things clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense to me. The statement `x += x` is equivalent to `x *= 2`, doubling `x`.

To help you understand, try printing `x` after every iteration:

```
x = 1
while x < 10:
    x += x
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
2
4
8
16
```

On each step:

```
2    # greater than 10? no
4    # greater than 10? no
8    # greater than 10? no
16   # greater than 10? yes, stop loop
```

Comment: and for the case that it is not clear (because as s/he told s/he is new to coding): `x += x` is equal to `x = x+x`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe changing the location of the `print(x)` could help you:

```
x = 1
print(1)
while x < 10:
    x += x
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
1
2
4
8
16
```

As you can see there is a common patron. Each iteration of the `while` duplicates the before value of `x` (that is due to `x += x`, which could be interpreted as double the x).

Then, the condition `while x < 10` is quite simple.

```
1     # Less than 10. Keep looping.
2     # Less than 10. Keep looping.
4     # Less than 10. Keep looping.
8     # Less than 10. Keep looping.
16    # Greater than 10. STOP!
```